# Which Xcode export methods are compatible with DeviceFarm?

Tags: ios, xcode, automated-tests, provisioning-profile, aws-device-farm

I've been trying to make sense of how to do test automation for an iOS app using AWS DeviceFarm and there seems to be a vacuum of information on how an .ipa is allowed to be installed and run on a random DeviceFarm iOS device. I'm a bit new to Xcode, so maybe I'm missing something.

In Xcode, when you archive a project you have to choose an export method.

[image]

I have to rule out the `App Store` option because my aim here is to test.

Then, the `Development` and `Ad Hoc` options require a list of `UDDI's`, and since the idea here is to test on DeviceFarm with whatever device they assign you on the fly, these two options seem to be ruled out.

Which only leaves the `Enterprise` option open. BUT... does this mean that in order to use DeviceFarm for iOS testing I must be enrolled in Apple's Enterprise Development Program??? Seems a bit harsh.

So, **which of these options are compatible with DeviceFarm, and why?** I mean, the only possible answers I can think of are:

- A) AWS has jail-broken all of their iOS devices and so the UDID list not relevant.
- B) AWS resigns all uploaded .ipa files with their own certificate and uses an Ad Hoc or Enterprise provisioning profile of their own to install and run them.

I'm aiming to use TestNG test scripts btw. Don't know if that's relevant or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mig82,

The iOS devices within AWS Device Farm are not jailbroken. In order to install custom applications on the devices, uploaded IPA files are resigned with a wildcard profile, as noted [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-runs.html#test-runs-app-resigning) in the documentation.

Exporting your app using Development Deployment should work just fine as it will sign it with your Developer Certificate but not require you to define a set of test devices by UDID.

Hope that helps!

Disclaimer: I previously worked on AWS Device Farm.

Comment: Thanks for that, @ahawker. That's really an awfully short paragraph. Hard to find unless you take the time to go over **all** the DeviceFarm documentation. I don't think I would've found it soon.

Comment: Use the Enterprise Distribution its better, correction to ahawker the Developer Deployment will need the UDID whereas the Universal Distribution Enterprise selected from screenshot given above will not need UDID.